# Vue.js(version 2.6.11) - How to get the click event for the next and previous click event for v-data-table pagination

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, v-data-table

I am fetching the records from the external API on demand. Need to load the data on click of next in the pagination. Here is my code

```
  <v-data-table
                  :headers="headers"
                  height="560"
                  fixed-header
                  :items="items"
                  v-model="selected"
                  show-select
                  item-key="itemkey"
                  :single-select="false"
                  :items-per-page=itemsPerPage
                  :server-items-length=500
                  :options.sync="options"
                  disable-filtering>
</v-data-table>

data() {
    return {
      tableHeight: 0,
      rowsPerPageItems: [10, 25, 50, 100],
      totalItems: 0,
      itemsPerPage: 10,
      options: {},
      headers: [
        { text: "Entity Id", value: "entityid", width: "235px", class: "black--text", sortable: true },
        { text: "Tenant Id", value: "tenantid", class: "black--text", width: "150px", sortable: true },
        { text: "Entity Type", value: "entitytype", class: "black--text", width: "150px", sortable: true },
        { text: "Time Stamp", value: "timestamp", class: "black--text", width: "150px", sortable: true },
        { text: "Action", value: "action", width: "100px", class: "black--text", sortable: false },
        { text: "Details", value: "details", class: "black--text", width: "50px", sortable: false },
      ],
      items: [],
      selected: [],
    };
  },
  methods: {
    async getDataFromAPI() {
      await this.FetchData(); // API responsible to fetch the data
    }
  },
```

I have a watch for the options as shown below

```
watch: {
    options: {
      handler() {
        console.log(this.options);
        const { sortBy, sortDesc, page, itemsPerPage } = this.options;
        if (this.items.length > 0) {
          this.getDataFromAPI();
          if (itemsPerPage > 0) {
            debugger;
            this.items = this.items.slice((page - 1) * itemsPerPage, page * itemsPerPage);
          }
        }
      },
      deep: true
    },
}
};
```

I am new to Vue.js and has less understanding on this.
My questions are as shown below.

1. How to have a click event for next and previous pages so that I can
   fetch records on click of these buttons? For now, the watch handler is invoked an every operation(both next and previous buttons)
2. How to enable the next button on some variable value? In my
   scenario, API returns a flag which says next set of records are
   available or not. So, If available next button should be enabled
   else disabled.
   Added the image to highlight the buttons
   For now, I am hard-coding the length to 500 to enable the next button
   [image]

Comment: Take a look at this. https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-data-table/#events-pagination

Comment: Use the `@update:options` event to handler server-side pagination and sorting. If you only need pagination without sorting then `update:page` can suffice.

Comment: If you don't mind can you please provide it with an example to identify if it is previous/ next page